# invalid parameter value while deploying Permission Sets

Tags: deployment, change-set, permission-sets

I'm trying to validate a Changeset which has 3 new permission sets and they all fail giving this error - invalid parameter value.

The permission sets includes read, edit, create permissions to few custom objects (No Modify All permissions given). And have included some VF Pages and Apex classes.

I'm just clueless about how to fix this. Appreciate any hints on this.

Comment: Can you please post the Apex? I'm willing to bet it's because you're referencing IDs or labels explicitly in your code.

Comment: Do you mean referencing Permission sets in the Apex code? I do with a query

Comment: Do you use IDs in that query, e.g. WHERE id = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx? Just so you know, IDs do not carry over from sandboxes, so if you programmatically explicitly reference them, it won't work

Comment: No, i don't reference IDs. Its just the name that I'm referencing. I removed the 3 PS and it gets validated. So trying to figure out whats wrong in the Permission sets

Comment: Are you including any profiles?

Comment: Nope, I'm not including any profiles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22473/discussion-between-helpsfdc-and-bri).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had custom permissions included into the Permission Sets which threw an error. I excluded the custom permissions from Permission Sets but have them in the Changeset. It deployed the changeset successfully.

Answer (score 0):

The problem we have seen is that there is a reference to a field (and most likely this would count for other config too) that is in your originating org and not in the destination org you get this error.

When you use Eclipse this can even mean that the list of permissions being passed includes everything showing true/false to be allowed by the Permission Set - so just the fact of adding a field in the destination org for an object that is being included (but not adding the field to the permission set) will mean you get this error.